# How to check the key exists in the event lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have event below

```
event = {'body-json': {}, 'params': {'path': {'match': '%20'}, 'querystring': {}, 'header': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'xx.amazonaws.com', 'Postman-Token': '50ae98db-6077-47c4-ac11-bfc53ac78990', 'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.2', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-5f2cb950-27ff7e6789988bd6b1a74d76', 'X-Forwarded-For': 'xxx.24', 'X-Forwarded-Port': '443', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https'}}, 'stage-variables': {}, 'context': {'account-id': '', 'api-id': 'xx', 'api-key': '', 'authorizer-principal-id': '', 'caller': '', 'cognito-authentication-provider': '', 'cognito-authentication-type': '', 'cognito-identity-id': '', 'cognito-identity-pool-id': '', 'http-method': 'POST', 'stage': 'v1', 'source-ip': 'xx.24', 'user': '', 'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.2', 'user-arn': '', 'request-id': '8d13e523-de12-4527-b58d-b11a7c8d09fb', 'resource-id': 'td4vr4', 'resource-path': '/{match}'}}
```

I have created a api gateway in AWS {match} in post method

my api gatewayurl is https://3xx.amazonaws.com/v1/Messi,Leo

`event['params']['path']['match'] = 'Messi,Leo'`

The problem

- if my apigateway url is https://3xx.amazonaws.com/v1/ if i put space after v1 am getting keyerror
- if i put special character like ($ space,dot)https://3xx.amazonaws.com/v1/$  I shouldnot get key error.
- Right now throwing `KeyError` error only if put Space after v1.
  You can see in event for match its '%20'
- if  KeyError i need to print there is `no result` i tried using try/except but still coming as key error

Code

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print (event) 
    var = event['params']['path']['match']
    #print (var)
    try :
        if var  == '':
            print ('tried')
    except Exception as e:
            print ('excepted')
```

Comment: What does your event look like when you have a space? Your key error is most likely raising because 'match' isn't present in that event. Your var assignment would need to be inside the try block if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using try\except, you need to wrap the error code in try\except:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print (event) 
    try:
        var = event['params']['path']['match']  # error here
        #print (var)
        if var  == '':
            print ('tried')
    except Exception as e:
            print ('excepted')
```

Comment: Is there any more native way?